# Setting up Nginx Load Balancing

Tags: web-hosting, nginx

I'm setting up an Nginx web server and and want to perform load balancing using the round robin method.  This is what I have found thus far:

```
upstream backend  {
   server backend1.example.com;
   server backend2.example.com;
   server backend3.example.com;
}
```

According to the page they says i need to add the above lines to my `nginx.conf` file and upload it to server to load balance.  I do not understand what it means by `server backend3.example.com;`.  How do I setup a backend instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the backend servers that will handle the incoming request.

So your domain's DNS should point to this nginx server, which will then use your upstream configuration to pass the request to one of the specified servers.

Your config should look something like this (inside http {} block)...

```
upstream backend  {
  server backend1.example.com;
  server backend2.example.com;
  server backend3.example.com;
}

server {
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
  }
}
```

**Some notes...**

- You can use the load balancer as another 'backend' if you want to.
- If you need https, then simply change `proxy_pass http://backend;` to `proxy_pass https://backend;` but make sure your backend servers are prepared to handle https.
- If your backend service uses sessions (such as PHP sessions), then you will need to setup some kind of session persistence, but that is unrelated.

You can find much more information for advanced configuration in the docs of nginx.

Comment: do i want to replace backend1.example.com,backend2.example.com;backend3.example.com, to any ip adress ??

Comment: @AvinashBabu I've updated my answer to explain a bit more. To answer your question, can you tell me how many backend servers you have? And yes, you can use IP addresses instead.

Comment: i havnt setup a backend server ...can you please tel me how can i setup one ..?/it would be really great if you tell me how

Comment: You can have a single server in the upstream backend.  I have a testing environment today that uses one server.  It doesn't require a minimum of two.

Comment: @jmq ..i dont know how can i setup a backend server ..can you both please tell me .

Comment: @AvinashBabu Load balancing can be quite an advanced setup. If you are not familiar / confident with it yet then I would suggest you do some research on the concept first. Once you've got more understanding and have attempted to set it up (use a tutorial) then you can ask for help if you run into any issues.

Comment: @jmq Ah ok, nice. I suppose that's used for testing the routing before adding another 1 or more backend servers?

Comment: @Clarkey i have researched a lot ..and am not going to do anything ..i just need information ..i just wanted to know how can i setup a backend server

Comment: A backend server is just another instance/server running nginx.  For example in AWS it would be another compute node.  You have the front end nginx server accept the request and it then proxy passes the request in a round robin algorithm to one of the servers in the list.

Comment: @Clarkey, yes to prove configuration and cheap, simple testing.

Comment: @jmq i didnt understood brother ..can you please elaborate or give me a link how to setup one ...

Comment: @jmq i just need to know how can i setup backend server ..its the question .pleae help me

Comment: @Avinash, do you have two servers today?  I'm assuming you have at least one server running nginx (a master instance).  You would setup another separate server running nginx as a node.  How did you setup your first server running nginx?

Comment: i have installed ngix and i tested my server on localhost and it works well ..

Comment: @AvinashBabu You need additional machines that are setup with a web server which are serving the same content to test load balancing with. You can't load balance nothing.

Comment: @Clarkey so i need another machine which runs ngix webserver ???..

Comment: @AvinashBabu Of course! I suggest you research into exactly what load balancing is first mate.

Comment: i have researched many times ....but i didnt understood anything ..see i dont have anyone to ask or clear my doubts ...i understand more when i ask someone ...thats why i asked ..so instead of backend1.example.com; backend2.example.com; i have to add the ipadress of the 2 machine which setup ngix right ?

Comment: @AvinashBabu Yup, that's right! You can use the hostname or IP address.

Comment: i really appreaciate ur help ..you give me an idea ..do i need to add the http.conf file on my webserver in the www directory ..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14257/discussion-between-clarkey-and-avinash-babu)

Comment: i came in chat ...

Comment: @AvinashBabu For some reason I can't log into stackexchange chat. Please do some more research and visit some tutorials on this.

Comment: do you use fb or any social networking websites ??

Comment: i have told you i have researched many times ..it would be really great if i can talk to you on fb or twitter like that...

Comment: @Clarkey can i setup a ngix webserver by creating a virtual machine instead of two new machines ...

Comment: Any webserver can act as a backend, it doesn't matter where the web server runs. I think you should study basic server operating principles in detail before trying to do any advanced stuff like load balancing. Without proper knowledge, you will only end up with more problems.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen well i have researched till morning ..and accroding to my understanding i think i need to setup ngix on multiple machines ..and i need to find the ip adress of those machines home server and add those ips to my httpd.conf file ..and restart my ngix ... right ??

Comment: will it work if i use the ip adress of a cloud server ??