# configuring loadbalacing with nigix

Tags: server

Hey guys i am trying to loadbalace my website with ngix..I have seen many tutorial and i have found one..According to tutorial i have seen that i need to add

```
upstream myCloud{

server s1.domain.com;;
  server 10.0.1.2;
  server 10.0.1.3;
}
```

those lines to my configuration file ..so  my question is that can i add a subdomain like something.domain.com to the server place ..Hope you guys can help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up Nginx Load Balancing](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61272/setting-up-nginx-load-balancing)

Comment: weli didnt found any useful ans there ..my qus is will it work  if i add a subdomain in the place of server ??

Comment: you already have this same question in another of your own posts.  You shouldn't repost the same question again.  I would recommend expanding on your other thread.

Comment: @jmq if you know just tell me the answer .....i didnt get an answer for that old question ..will it work if i add a subdomain ???